# How to save a list with SharedPreferences?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I tried to save a `List` (which is called `test`)with two `variables` with `SharedPreferences`. I tried the code below, but I get some errors. Does anybody see the mistake i made? (I think it´s kind of an easy to fix mistake, but I´m a beginner and can´t find it ;)

```
     int counter1 = 0;
     int counter2 = 20;
     String nameKey = "eins";
     var test = [counter1, counter2]; 
     @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
      }

      Future<bool> save() async {
        SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        return await preferences.setIntList(nameKey, test);
      }

 Future<List<int>> load() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getIntList(nameKey);
  }

      set() {
        load().then((value) {
          setState(() {
            test = value;
          });
        });
      }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cache two Lists in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61560373/cache-two-lists-in-flutter)

Comment: Please check the answer.

Comment: I don´t get it... I don´t understand theexample you mean :(

Answer (score 0):

```
 Future<List<String>> load() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return preferences.getStringList(nameKey);
  }
```