# Best approach to logout Provider and Shared preferences

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-provider

I have my ChangeNotifier class , which is supposed to trigger the logout session tracking, but it has failed to work, what is the cleaner way of implementing this, this is my ChnageNotifier code :

```
class ProfileTracker with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isAuthenticated = false;
  static const String AUTH_TRACKER = "AUTH_TRACKER";

  void setUp(val)async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _isAuthenticated =  await prefs.setBool(AUTH_TRACKER, val);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool get isAuthenticated {
    return this._isAuthenticated;
  }

  set isAuthenticated(bool newVal) {
    setUp(newVal);
    this.notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Then , this is the code I set when logging in :

```
 var profileTracker =
              Provider.of<ProfileTracker>(context, listen: false);

            profileTracker.isAuthenticated = true;
```

While logging out, I use :

```
var profileTracker =
              Provider.of<ProfileTracker>(context, listen: false);

            profileTracker.isAuthenticated = false;
```

But the code doesn't seem to work when I logout, the state doesn't get stored in shared preferences.

Answer (score 1):

You can clean the shared_preference storage as following in a method in provider

```dart
void logout() async{
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await preferences.clear();
  this._isAuthenticated = false;
  this.notifyListeners();
}
```

You can call this method to logout using the provider object and change the page after the logout is notified.

Comment: This will just clear all the shared prefs, and then secondly I don't see here how you have stored the `this._isAuthenticated`, if I kill the app and come back I'll be loggedIn

Comment: You can create `init()` which should fetch this value from shared_preference for `isAuthenticated` when the app starts and you can redirect the user on home page if you get the value as `true`

Comment: I dont want to clear all the shared prefs, I just wanted to look for a way of attaching the  shared prefs in the getters and setters of ChangeNotifier

Comment: You can create separate utility for shared_preferences and use it during starting of the app. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61562949/4788260)