# Save a List to SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to save the list dragged from the sql to be saved in `SharedPreferences`, I tried using this code:

```
static Future<List<User>> getUsers() async {
    final myUserId = await getUser();
    try {
      var myUser = myUserId;
      var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
      map['user'] = myUser;
      final response = await http.post(ROOT, body: map);
      //print('getUsers Response: ${response.body}');
      //print(myUser);
      if (200 == response.statusCode) {
        List<User> listContacts = parseResponse(response.body);
        SharedPreferences contacts = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        contacts.setStringList('contacts', listContacts);
        return listContacts;
      } else {
        return List<User>();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return List<User>(); // return an empty list on exception/error
    }
  }
```

the `User` class for the list is the following:

```
class User {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String imageLink;

  User({this.firstName, this.lastName, this.imageLink});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return User(
      firstName: json['firstName'] as String,
      lastName: json['lastName'] as String,
      imageLink: json['imageLink'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

So basically the data is successfully pulling it out from the database, and it does display it, but I want to save the data to `SharedPreferences` so it doesn't have to load every single time. The error that is occurring is that the `listContacts` can't be assigned to `setStringList`, since it is a `List<User>` and not a `List<String>`, but I don't know how else can I change the code in order to be able to set the `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: can you try `contacts.setString('contacts',json.encode(listcontacts))` what I am doing is again encoding it to a json format you can also save your json response and later extract it using your class

Comment: @Krish Bhanushali, it does work the way you said. But after I store it how can I use it again? and how do I set it to the Map?

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61562949/4788260)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can do is

```
static Future<List<User>> getUsers() async {
final myUserId = await getUser();
try {
  var myUser = myUserId;
  var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
  map['user'] = myUser;
  final response = await http.post(ROOT, body: map);
  //print('getUsers Response: ${response.body}');
  //print(myUser);
  if (200 == response.statusCode) {

    List<User> listContacts = parseResponse(response.body);
    SharedPreferences contacts = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    contacts.setString('contacts',json.encode(response.body)); //Here saved the response
    return listContacts;
  } else {
    return List<User>();
  }
} catch (e) {
  return List<User>(); // return an empty list on exception/error
}


 }
```

Now to fetch it I can use is

```
SharedPreferences contacts = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
var response = json.decode(contacts.getString('contacts'));
List<User> listContacts = parseResponse(response.body);
```

and you get back your data from shared preferences

Comment: Does the fetch code go inside the static Future or I have to create another one outside?

Comment: it will work since its async already. But better is you fetch it from outside just for a clear understanding

Comment: ooh... Sorry @Krish Bhanushali, but there is a problem with the response.body when fetching it...